# Image plot of integer lattice through a map

Tags: plotting, lattices

Is there a way to plot (in the real line) the points corresponding to the image of

$$
L(n_{1},n_{2})=\alpha\cdot n_{1}+\beta\cdot n_{2},
$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real numbers to be chosen and $(n_{1},n_{2})\in\mathbb{Z}^{2}$? I would just like to see how the image of this map is distributed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this problem makes sense at least in Mathematica unless it's constrained in a way or another. Given unlimited range over $\mathbb{Z}^{2}$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ assumed not being rational multiples of each other, there are going to be infinitely many solutions on any given range.

Consider, for instance thousand solutions in $[0,1]$ with constants $e$ and $\pi$:

```
NumberLinePlot[
 E n1 + Pi n2 /. 
  FindInstance[0 <= E n1 + Pi n2 <= 1, {n1, n2}, Integers, 1000]]
```

[image]

You are going to find as many solutions as you want on this unit range in this case, and not going to see any real structure (and please note that `FindInstance` does provide instance solutions, but doesn't give any sort of guarantees on their distribution).

This problem would make more sense if $(n_{1},n_{2})\in\mathbb{Z}^{2}_{\geq 0}$, where we can find all solutions for a range:

```
NumberLinePlot[
 E n1 + Pi n2 /. 
  Solve[0 <= E n1 + Pi n2 <= 20, {n1, n2}, NonNegativeIntegers]]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**: It is possible to see (rather obvious) patterns on the values of $(n_{1},n_{2})$ that image to a specific interval on the real number line. For instance:

```
ListPlot[{n1, n2} /. 
  Solve[-50 <= n1 <= 50 && -50 <= n2 <= 50 && 
    0 <= E n1 + Pi n2 <= 10, {n1, n2}, Integers], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done as follows.

```
r = Partition[Flatten[Table[{n1, n2}, {n1, -3, 3}, {n2, -3, 3}]], 2]; 
ListPlot[r, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Then

```
ListPlot[Map[Function[p, {2 p[[1]] - Sqrt[2]*p[[2]], 0}], r]]
```

[image]